# Excel VBA find unique values in combinations of 2 or more columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a module with a for loop to count the unique values of 3 combining columns containing the status of payment day, the month and the year of a date. Said date is separated because each of them refer to a cycle of the month and everything is sorted by year, month and day in this exact order. Like the simplified small example below.

```
STATUS: DAY : MONTH : YEAR
PAID: 1   : 7     : 2016
OPEN: 1   : 7     : 2016
PAID: 1   : 7     : 2016
OPEN: 5   : 7     : 2016
PAID: 5   : 7     : 2016
OPEN: 5   : 7     : 2016
PAID: 10  : 7     : 2016
OPEN: 10  : 7     : 2016
PAID: 10  : 7     : 2016
PAID: 15  : 7     : 2016
PAID: 15  : 7     : 2016
OPEN: 15  : 7     : 2016
```

What i tried to do was to compare all 3 cells with the next cell of the columns, if they were equal in all 3 cases i would simply count it to see how many unique values i had of this date and save it on a separate sheet. If it is different in any of cases it would simply add the date to the second sheet and start counting from there. The code below is simplified for convenience and because the macro i'm working on is way too big to post here.
EDIT: If needed i can post upload the complete code somewhere, i'll just to translate some of the variables and comments.

```
j = 3 '' variable referencing the next line after i
k = 1 '' variable referencing the lines of the second sheet.
For i = 2 To lastrow ''variable to count how many rows the first sheet has

    j = j + 1 ''variable to check the very next line after i

    If w1.Range("A" & i).Value = "PAID" Then
        If w1.Range("H" & i).Value = w1.Range("H" & j) And w1.Range("G" & i).Value = w1.Range("G" & j) And w1.Range("F" & i).Value = w1.Range("F" & j) Then ''if statement to check if all 3 cells are equal to the next 3 cells 
            w2.Range("D" & K).Value = w2.Range("D" & K).Value + 1 '' Sum 1 to the total number of dates with equal parameters on the 3 cells


        Else '' writes the new date in the second sheet
            K = K + 1
            w2.Range("A" & K).Value = w1.Range("H" & i).Value
            w2.Range("B" & K).Value = w1.Range("G" & i).Value
            w2.Range("C" & K).Value = w1.Range("F" & i).Value
            w2.Range("D" & K).Value = 1

        End If
    End If

Next i
```

What i get is usually the first date with everything counted on a single line in the new sheet and the very data of the very last row in the second line.

I also tried to use dictionaries and/or collections but i didn't quite get the concept of them even on some examples i have found on stack overflow and on the internet.

How do i make this loop work or what would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the unique combinations from ***4*** columns:

```
Sub uniKue()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3) & " " & Cells(i, 4)
    Next i

    Range("E2:E" & N).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

You can extend the approach for as many columns as needed:

- concatenate the columns
- use the *RemoveDuplicates* feature in the Ribbon's *Data* tab

**EDIT#1:**

This version:

```
Sub uniKue()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3) & " " & Cells(i, 4)
        Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 5)
    Next i

    Range("F:F").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    For Each r In Range("F:F").SpecialCells(2).Offset(, 1)
        r.Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E," & r.Offset(, -1).Address & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

Column **E** is the full combination set.
Column **F** is the unique set.
Column **G** is the number of occurrences of each unique item.
Once completed, column **E** can be hidden.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that i need to sum the amount of times said values show up. How would i go about that?

Comment: Do you need to **count** how many times each unique combination shows up in the full dataset ???

Comment: I need to show how many different datasets i have and how many times they show up right next to it.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man  See if you can adapt my **EDIT#1** to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of distinct rows (8), this Excel Formula can be used (in VBA too):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1 / COUNTIFS(A2:A13,A2:A13, B2:B13,B2:B13, C2:C13,C2:C13, D2:D13,D2:D13) )
```

To get the number of unique rows that don't have duplicates (4):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--( COUNTIFS(A2:A13,A2:A13, B2:B13,B2:B13, C2:C13,C2:C13, D2:D13,D2:D13)=1 ))
```

---

In VBA, Excel formulas can be calculated with the [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-evaluate-method-excel) method:

```
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

uniqueCount = Sheet1.Evaluate(Replace( _
      "SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A2:A3,A2:A3,B2:B3,B2:B3,C2:C3,C2:C3,D2:D3,D2:D3)=1))", 3, lastRow))

Debug.Print uniqueCount    ' 4
```

You can also get the counts of all rows at once (faster than calling Excel for each cell separately):

```
countsArray = Sheet1.Evaluate(Replace( _
      "Transpose(CountIfs(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,B2:B9,C2:C9,C2:C9,D2:D9,D2:D9))", 9, lastRow))

' Debug.Print Join(countsArray)   ' "2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1"
' Debug.Print Evaluate("SUM(--({" & Join(countsArray, ",") & "}=1))") ' 4
' Debug.Print Evaluate("SUM(1/{" & Join(countsArray, ",") & "})")     ' 8

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If countsArray(i - 1) = 1 Then
        ' ... no dumplicates
    Else
        ' .. has duplicates
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: how do i apply that in VBA?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I am not sure if you need just the count or the rows, so I added examples for both. If you need just the PAID Status count, you can replace `A2:A3,A2:A3,` with `A2:A3,""PAID"",`