# VBA | How to count occurrences for distinct values?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help with the issue below?
How to count for each distinct value from **Column "A"** how many times the value in **Column "B"** appears with the criteria (e.g. ">30") ? In the perfect world it would be multiple criteria.

In Columns A:B - source data, in Columns E:F is the expected result. Also, it could be separated between two sheets.

[Source data and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmRiv.png)

The code I've found so far extracts only the unique values from one sheet to another and count its occurrences in the entire range.

```
Sub UniqueIdentifiers()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim count As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 2
j = 2
Do Until i > lastRow
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & lastRow), Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3))
        For Each c In Sheets(1).Range("C" & lastRow).Cells
        
            Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
            Sheets(2).Cells(j, 2) = count
            
            j = j + 1
            
        Next
    i = i + 1
Loop
    Sheets(2).Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
        
End Sub
```

**UPDATE - THE ISSUE WAS SOLVED**

I've managed to find the solving for my task thanks @Gary's Student answer in [Excel VBA find unique values in combinations of 2 or more columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911258/excel-vba-find-unique-values-in-combinations-of-2-or-more-columns)
 question just added to his code if condition. The full code is below:

```
Sub uniKue()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, 4) >= 30 Then
        Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 5)
        Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 5)
    End If
    Next i
    Range("F:F").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    For Each r In Range("F:F").SpecialCells(2).Offset(, 1)
        r.Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E," & r.Offset(, -1).Address & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Thanks to all for contribution.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: It will be the part of another macro and I would prefer to do it in vba to avoid every time writing the formula

Comment: You can write a formula using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This go's through your list of NRs in **column A** and finds each instance than adds it to **columns E** if it is not present. If it is present it adds to 1 each time it finds this instance in **column F**

```
Option Explicit
Sub UniqueIdentifiers()

Dim Nrs As Range 'list all Nrs
Dim Nr As Range 'each indiviual Nr in the list of Nrs
Dim Item As Range 'each indivual item in the other column
Dim adder As Range 'used to find item and add it if nessesary

Set Nrs = Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)) 'you can also change this ofcourse to a specific range or user selected


For Each Nr In Nrs
    Set adder = Range("e2", Range("e2").End(xlDown)).Find(Nr)
    If adder Is Nothing Then
        If Range("e2") = "" Then
            Set Item = Range("e2")
        Else
            Set Item = Range("e1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Item.Value = Nr.Value
        Item.Offset(0, 1) = 1
    Else
        adder.Offset(0, 1).Value = adder.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
    End If
Next Nr


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unique Count (Dictionary)

- Adjust the values in the constants section. Also, adjust the greater than (`>`) at `'***` if necessary.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueIdentifiers()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const sCrit As Double = 30
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "E2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim wasDataFound As Boolean
    
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            Data = .Resize(sCell.Row - .Row + 1, 2).Value
            wasDataFound = True
        End If
    End With
    
    If wasDataFound Then

        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim i As Long
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            If Data(i, 2) > sCrit Then '***
                dict(Data(i, 1)) = dict(Data(i, 1)) + 1
            Else
                If Not dict.Exists(Data(i, 1)) Then
                    dict(Data(i, 1)) = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    
        If dict.Count > 0 Then
            
            ReDim Data(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 2)
            i = 0
            
            Dim Key As Variant
            
            For Each Key In dict.Keys
                i = i + 1
                Data(i, 1) = Key
                Data(i, 2) = dict(Key)
            Next Key
            
            With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, 2)
                .Resize(i).Value = Data
                .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.count - .Row - i + 1) _
                    .Offset(i).ClearContents
            End With
            
        End If
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbExclamation, "No Data"
    
    End If

End Sub
```